# FinexApi : Keyprice should be a decimal number, e.g. "123.456"

Tags: python

I'm trying to edit a simple code for automated put and take action on bitfinex market using FinexApi.

I get this error while performing a subtraction

Keyprice should be a decimal number, e.g. "123.456"

this is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#Places a put and take above and below current market price
import FinexAPI

diff = 0.00000150 #The amount above or below market price you want
ticker = FinexAPI.ticker()
available = float(FinexAPI.balances()[2]["available"])
ask = float(ticker["ask"])
amount = 1 #Amount of XRP to place orders

marketPrice = ticker["last_price"]
buyPrice = float(marketPrice) - diff
sellPrice = float(marketPrice) + diff

print FinexAPI.place_order(str(amount), str(buyPrice), "buy", "exchange limit")
print FinexAPI.place_order(str(amount), str(sellPrice), "sell", "exchange limit")
```

I get error on:

```
print FinexAPI.place_order(str(amount), str(buyPrice), "buy", "exchange limit")

Keyprice should be a decimal number, e.g. "123.456"
```

Let's assume marketPrice is 0.00003500
I would like the code to make a buy order at marketPrice - diff ( 0.00003500 - 0.00000150 ) and a sell order at marketPrice + diff ( 0.00003500 + 0.00000150 )
but I keep getting the same error.

I tried to put the diff number inside " ", I tried using decimal, I tried a few bunch of things but I got other errors or no solution at all.

I'm quite noobish at python, can someone help me and tell me what am I doing wrong, or how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: SOLVED importing decimal and replacing float(marketPrice) to Decimal(marketprice), and setting up diff as a decimal too.

Thanks